How to use the command line option menu dialog box?
For example, with the tool 'needrestart' in interactive mode, it creates an option dialog after a system update. But i dont understand how to select or deselect options. I cannot seem to even find the term for this popup, much less an article describing how to use it.
for reference im talking about the dialog box shown here as well: apt-get upgrade auto restart services
e: using tuxedoOS, so ubuntu 23 LTS + kde rolling (iirc)

What version of Ubuntu are you using? Please edit and add the info to the question.

FWIW it's basically the same text user interface (TUI) as here: In "Tasksel" how do I select a package?

Such menus are usually created using ncurses. I don't really know where this is documented, I'm afraid, but usually, they work like this:

Up and Down arrow keys to move up and down.
Space to select/deselect options.
Tab to cycle through menu sections (e.g. to move to the OK or Cancel options in the screenshot you linked to).
Enter to activate the selected option (e.g. to "click" on the OK).

